# Image Hyperlink in ASP.NET - MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I try to create a project for the first time in asp.net (mvc4).

and what i try to do is to create a image which is a hyperlink to go to the index page.

i have search a lot of things and it shows very simple to do that.

but i can´t understand why it doesn´t work for me.

someone can give a hand?

Code:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("Index","Home")%><img src="~/Content/imagens/nav-arrow-back.png"/></a>
```

The Action is "Index" in the controller calls Home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, as previously noted you're missing a closing quote on that `href`. Second, MVC 4 doesn't use the `<% %>` syntax, at least not by default; it should be using Razor v2 which uses `@`, so your code should look like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")"><img src="~/Content/imagens/nav-arrow-back.png"/></a>
```

If you use the old syntax I assume it would try to handle the actual text `<%= Url.Action("Index","Home")%>` as a URL, which clearly won't work.

Answer (score 2):

you miss a quote

```
<a href="<%=Url.Action("Index","Home")%>">  ...
                                        ^
                                      about this quote you missed
```

For bad request, fix the whole `<img>` part

```
<img src="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/imagens/nav-arrow-back.png")%>"/>
```